# How to disable a subset of general created jQuery tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tooltip

We have the current situation that we need to disable some tooltips when an overlay menu opens. Since all tooltips are generally created using `$(document).tooltip()`, it somehow doesn't work when disabling a subset of the created tooltips, e.g. `$('a.special').tooltip('disable')`.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" title="special tooltip" class="special">Link</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).tooltip(); // works :)

$('button').click(function () {
    // -> How can we make this work?
    $('a.special').tooltip('disable'); // doesn't work :(
});
```

---

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WJVQ2/)

**How can we make this work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WJVQ2/7/)**

Apply tooltip to all elements using `'*'` as selector and not `document`. It initialises tooltip on document object and not elements.

Use this snippet,

```
$('*').tooltip();

$('button').click(function () {
    $('#message').show();
    $('a.special').tooltip('disable');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now that I see the solution, I feel like it was abvious. But then, you always need the right angle to approach... well done.

Comment: Well, now I still got the problem that some tooltips are not yet initialized (during delay) at the time when I want to disable them. Is it possible to select (all) tooltips which are already initialized?